# Semaphore with priority

Tags: c#, multithreading, semaphore

I know about the `Semaphore` class in the `System.Threading` namespace, but I don't see if it  allows waiting threads to have different priorities levels.

If two threads are waiting for an open slot, is there a way to allow the thread with the higher priority to have the first open slot available?

Answer (score 3):

From the [MSDN documentantion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) on the Semaphore class

> There is no guaranteed order, such as
>   FIFO or LIFO, in which blocked threads
>   enter the semaphore.

But take a look at these two projects which both supports priority for threads.

[Smart Thread Pool](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/smartthreadpool.aspx)

[Thread-safe priority queue in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/Thread-safePriorityQueueC.aspx)