# Counting threads with lock and without (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, synchronization

[Grant Crofton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3465873/200449) to the question "Unordered threads problem" has a comment:

> "And if you remove the lock the final count might be less than 100."

Why?

Here is the code for context

```
class Program
{
    static object locker = new object();
    static int count=0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            (new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(dostuff))).Start(j);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void dostuff(object Id)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            count++;
            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0}: Count is {1}", Id, count);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what *could* happen **without** a lock:

```
Count = 0

ThreadA Reads Count As 0 
ThreadB Reads Count As 0
ThreadA Writes New Incremented Count As 0 + 1
ThreadB Writes New Incremented Count As 0 + 1

Count = 1
```

These are called [Race Conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) and are solved by making the operation [Atomic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability)

```
Count = 0

ThreadB Wins Race To Lock()
ThreadB Reads Count As 0
ThreadB Writes New Incremented Count As 0 + 1
ThreadB Unlocks

ThreadA Next for Lock()
ThreadA Reads Count As 1
ThreadA Writes New Incremented Count As 1 + 1
ThreadA Unlocks

Count = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the lock protects the `count` variable from multiple threads trying to increment it at once. Which if that occurs, may give you strange results.

The lock ensures that threads can only enter your function one at a time, and therefore do the operations inside it one at a time only.

If you remove it, then threads can enter at the same time, be interrupted while in the middle of any of these operations and give you strange results, out of order results, etc.

Comment: Strange results imply also more than 100?!

Comment: No, because the loop that starts your threads is not going past a hundred.